# In Stake Land, any clear explanation as to why the travelers did not stay in the town?

Tags: vampire, stake-land

The man and his "apprentice" manage to gain admittance to an apparently well-defended town which is very functional -- the kid gets a haircut, there is food, etc. But soon they leave and are subject to not just the obvious dangers but simple privations -- they sleep in a car, there is no running water, etc.

IIRC, the town folk seem willing to accept them, at least the kid. I know their goal is a northern settlement that due to the cold (again, IIRC) is safer from the vampires. Is that the basic reason, that "Mister", despite the town's thriving appearance, suspects that eventually such a densely-populated place is doomed to be attacked, either by wandering vampires or by the cult?

Comment: @Valorum: That is the logical explanation but if you watch the film, the town sure seems like taking a chance on. For indeed, if an organized setup like that town is doomed to be overrun, humanity existing in a few small settlements in Canada while the rest of the continent becomes zombies I doubt, cold or no, such settlements will last either. They would die out from lack of food, etc. Also, zombpires are not the only problem they face -- there is a vicious cult which distinguishes this film brilliantly.

Comment: @Valorum: Yes, it does. I had forgotten that bit and I guess why I forgot is it is not very compelling.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that they've have largely set their sights on getting to New Eden. Their shared experience has been that population centres tend to attract bloodsuckers and their feeling seems to be that the township really isn't any different, doomed to be overrun, if not today, then tomorrow or soon.

> "Uh, Mister says less population, less bloodsuckers."

They do consider staying (or at least the boy does), but their goal is further north where they feel they'll actually be safe, not just safe for a while.

> "Sometimes I think I could stay in a place like this. Make friends, live in the daylight. Just be a kid. But the truth is I don't feel safe around people. They can think what they want, but New Eden was real. It was the answer to all of this and we were gonna find it. Fight our way north, make the open territories. Like Mister says. 'Live free or die tryin'."

Comment: Yeah, if you see what happens to them, it does not make sense. Unless the townsfolk insisted upon a permanent commitment, spending a month or two there to recuperate would be what anyone would do even if bound for a place that they really don't know exists. This is btw almost exactly a plot element from I am Legend.

Comment: @releseabe - You wait in a dangerous place too long, you're certain to get overrun and killed. Better to take your chances on the road.

Comment: I sure would prefer to part of a community that had prepared to defend itself -- the perils of the vambies and the cult, i sure would not to be just two guys in a rickety car.

Comment: @releseabe - If your expectation is that they're doomed in the next couple of years, then staying for any longer than you absolutely have to is a terrible idea. I wouldn't risk my life on a 1/600ish chance compared to the open road.